# How to return a valid data instead of (null, 0). Moq, mock

Tags: c#, .net, moq, xunit

I try to mock a method of a service. The method returns a `TupleValue` with `(List<AnyViewModel>, int)`.

The mock which I use

```
mockService.Setup(s => s.GetAll(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync((testViewModels, countOfEntities))
```

In this case, the mock returns `(null, 0)`.

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

**UPD**

Interface

```cs
public Task<(List<AnyViewModel>, int)> GetAll(int Id, string? search = null);
```

I tried to collect data like this

```cs
var tupleToReturn = ValueTuple.Create<List<AnyViewModel>, int>(testViewModels, countOfEntities);

// mock block
mockService.Setup(s => s.GetAll(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(tupleToReturn)
```

It doesn't work

Comment: Seems your expected return type and the parameter order in setup is mixed up. Could you post the interface definition you try to mock. I would guess it uses some generic parameters and thus allows any parameter order.

Comment: @Oliver added, but i don't think so

Comment: Maybe it's only the missing nullable sign for the second parameter `It.IsAny<string>()` that keeps Moq from linking the call with the setup. Does `It.IsAny<string?>()` work?

Comment: @Markus checked, nope=(

Comment: If you set the mock behavior to strict, you encounter an error, if a call cannot be linked to a setup. This shows the call that is made so that you can compare it to your setup. Can you set the mock behavior to strict in the constructor when instantiating the mock?

Comment: @Markus It works=),thx. why does it work? I have no exceptions, but the test is passed... `mockService = new Mock<IMyInterface>(MockBehavior.Strict);`

Comment: Strange, `MockBehavior.Strict` should not change the way the setups work in terms of matching with calls.

Comment: @Markus anyway, that helped. I tried this on serveral tests.